# How to show rdlc report as pdf in mozzzilla pdf viewer?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, report, rdlc

I have some asp.net application, which contains 3 rdlc reports. I open those reports in report viewer and it works great. I can download report as pdf file, and also print it from report viewer. Now what I would like to do is this (only if using mozzilla browser): I want to show only pdf file of the report in browser, actually in mozzila pdf viewer. here is the link as an example: http://www.selab.isti.cnr.it/ws-mate/example.pdf (open it in mozzila).
And also i would like to know if this could be done with javascript. Just to mention, i open this reports on button click.
Hope I was clear enough with my question, if you need some more info let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not javascript but here's how I would do it.  For simplicity I'm assuming the report is already loaded into the reportviewer.

In your button click event handler:

```
//perform check for mozilla... see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3yekbd5b

if (browser.Name == mozilla)
{
    //get report from viewer
    byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF"); 

    //display pdf in browser
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=MyReport.pdf");
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.End();
}
```

Let me know if I missed something but I think understood what you wanted.

Comment: Not exactly solved my problem, but clearly helped alot. Thank you!